# Grant write permission to the docker volume mounted

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I created a node app that **"reads and writes"** to files .
this works fine when ran  .
But when i mount it to  docker

```
docker  run -it --rm -v   ${pwd}:/files -w /files -p:3000:3000 node:latest node index
```

though i am able to read from files but unable to write to them..

gives error: when writing to file

{"errno":-13,"code":"EACCES","syscall":"open","path":"./public/b.txt"}

[works fine when ran without docker ]

Do we have to give write permission  explicitly..

```
function grants() {
fs.chmod("./public", 0o765, e => {
    let g = 'granted i think';
    if (e) {
        g = JSON.stringify(e);
    }
    console.log(g);
})
```

}
to this but still no luck

Comment: You're mounting `/files`, but your write error refers to `/public`?

Comment: but i am performin both read and write opreations on same file...i an successfullly able to read ..but not write

Comment: @daniu i am mounting  entire app directory and public is a folder inside it ...so if we are mounting volume ...do we have to  perform seperate fs.chmod

Comment: can you share dockerfile file ?

Comment: Your host platform and docker version/type you're using, please

Comment: platform: windows 10 _____Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962 @k-lusine

Comment: Where's that index.js file initially, on host?